# Why custom directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement me custom directive of AngularJS.

Let's say the code look like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' ng-app='testApp'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'/>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'/>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="searchinput.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <searchInput></searchInput>
    </body>
</html>
```

**searchInput.js**

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);
testApp.directive("searchInput", function() {
    return {
          replace:true,
          restrict: 'AE',
          template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
      }
});
```

Unfortunately I didn't see the expected result . Does anyone know anything I missed ? thanks.

Comment: Do as instructed by below answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
<searchInput></searchInput>
```

to

```
<search-input></search-input>
```

check it out in the **[AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives)** for more details

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even having a hyphen didn't help. The entire tag had to be in lowercase (on angularjs/1.3.16).

My custom directive `textReplace` did not work initially. Then, I checked with `text-replace`, which also did not work. Finally, checked with `textreplace`, which worked.